# Is passing functions as arguments in JS really needed?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I'm starting to learn JS and so far I have come across functions.

I understood how to pass a variable value between functions passing it as an argument in the function call and receiving it into a parameter in the function declaration.
One thing I'm not getting that much is function passing between functions.

As far as I can understand, we can pass a function as an argument to another function and then use the passed function inside of the function that received it.

```
function pass (x){
   return ("Hello + " x);
}

function receivePass(value, func){
   console.log(func(value));
}

receivePass("John", pass);
```

This example explains this "function passing" thing.

However, why don't just write it like this

```
function pass (x){
   return ("Hello + " x);

function output(value){
   console.log(pass(value));
}

output( "John");
```

I really don't get it, the second seems much easier to read and does not create any confusion.

Can somebody explain why function passing is used? In which cases does it provide any advantage? What would be the cleaner code between the 2 examples?

Comment: Your alternative assumes that the function knows what function to call. That is of course not always the case; the whole point of an API like that is to make it possible to pass in **any** function as the callback.

Comment: Can you make a simple example on a function that does not know the other function to call and need the function to be passed as an argument please?

Comment: An ajax callback is a classic. you call ajax() method and pass to it the function that will handle the output.

Comment: @LorenzoZabot consider a function that gets imported into another module to be used there. How could it possibly know what function to call?